# Mobile menu back to front on small media

Tags: html, css

A quick question.

My list(li) is floated right but when the media size is for small screen its shows back to front.  I'm sure its a simple fix but I've had no success.
Any help would be great, thank you in advance.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav bar 1 w3s.css" />
</head>

<body>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="#Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Extra">Extra</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Writings">Writings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>


body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

/*remove margins and padding from the LIST, and add a black background color*/
ul.topnav{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#333;
}

/*float the LIST (li) items side by side*/
ul.topnav li{
    float:right;
}

/*style the (a)links inside the LI items*/
ul.topnav li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#f2f2f2;
    text-align:center;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size:17px;
}


/*change backround color of the LINKS (a) on hover*/
ul.topnav li a:hover{
    background-color:#555;
}


/*hide the list (li) items that contains the link that 
should open and close-quotethe topnav on small screens*/
ul.topnav li.icon{
    display:none;
}


/*when the screen is less than 680px hide,hide all list (li)items,
except the first one("Home"). Show the list(li) item that contains
the link (a) open and close the topnav (li.icon)*/


@media screen and (max-width:680px){

    ul.topnav li:not(:first-child){
        display:none;
        }

        ul.topnav li.icon{
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        }

/*float the LIST (li) items side by side*/
ul.topnav li{
    float:left;
}
    }

/*the "responsive" class is added to the topnav with Javascript when the uses
clicks on the (icon).  This class makes the topnav look good on small screens*/
@media screen and (max-width:680px){
    ul.topnav.responsive {
        position:relative;
    }

ul.topnav.responsive li.icon{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float:none;
    display:inline;
}

ul.topnav.responsive li a{
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
}

}
```

Comment: Its bound to happen, in mobile you made `float: none` to the `<li>` so its just behaving in the order mentioned in the HTML

Comment: I've tried putting it into the correct order in the HTML, then i have issues putting the nav to the right

Comment: A weird stylesheet link href: `href="nav bar 1 w3s.css"`.

Comment: and extreme definition: `*{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }`

Comment: You've defined a query `@media screen and (max-width:680px)` twice

Comment: yeah weird name as i have done so many tests lol

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in your case I will suggest the best recommended solution - **Using Flexbox**

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/zojWJy)

Since the code you pasted is quiet shabby straight from your experiment book I can say, it took some time for me to identify the unnecessary codes. I am going to give a step by step of how to achieve what you want from your current code.

1) **Firstly arrange the HTML the right way(`<Home> ..to.. <Contact Us>`)**

2) **Make your `<ul>` a flex-box & float its children(`<li>`) to the right using**

```
ul.topnav{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#333;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end; /*float its children to right*/
}
```

3) **Now on mobile float those children to the left & arrange the menus in columns(vertically) using**

```
@media screen and (max-width:680px){
  ul.topnav {
    justify-content: flex-start; /*float its children to left*/
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  ...other styles...
}
```

4) **Now make the the hamburger icon(`.icon`) position absolute always in mobile mode not just when the menu expands.**

To do this remove the `ul.topnav.responsive li.icon` styles from `@media screen and (max-width:680px`. Merge those with `ul.topnav li.icon`

New **merged** code would look like

```
  ul.topnav li.icon{
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```

Apart from these rest of the code should remain the same, ofcourse except the indentation & redundant media query calls etc.